# importing odoo templates on eclipse IDE

Tags: xml, eclipse, templates, odoo

i'm trying to set up eclipse IDE for Odoo modules development, so I used the templates :

Openerp-eclipse-xml-template.xml
templates-openerp.xml

I did the import : windows --> preferences --> XML --> XML files --> editor --> templates  then import 
but whenever I try to open an XML file there is no snippets !

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pydev plugin to eclipse ?

[update site](http://pydev.org/updates/)

Did you create a pydev project ?

Import should be done through

```
Preferences > pydev > editor > templates > import
```

Comment: yes i did it all , and the its working with pydev but not with xml ?